# ms access max count

Tags: sql, ms-access

Here is my query:

```
SELECT Count(*) AS CountOfJoker, tblPrediction.GameID
FROM (tblUser INNER JOIN (tblPool INNER JOIN tblUserPool ON tblPool.PoolID = tblUserPool.PoolID) ON tblUser.UserID = tblUserPool.UserID) INNER JOIN (tblResult INNER JOIN tblPrediction ON tblResult.GameID = tblPrediction.GameID) ON tblUser.UserID = tblPrediction.UserID
GROUP BY tblPrediction.GameID, tblPrediction.Joker, tblResult.GroupName, tblPool.PoolID
HAVING (((tblPrediction.Joker)=True) AND ((tblResult.GroupName)='A') AND ((tblPool.PoolID)=314));
```

Here is the output:

```
CountOfJoker    GameID
2       1
2       2
2       9
1       10
1       17
3       18
```

I would like the MAX of CountOfJoker with the following output:

```
CountOfJoker    GameID
3       18
```

Thanks
Drew

Answer (score 1):

You could use `select top` and `order by ... desc`

```
    SELECT TOP 1 Count(*) AS CountOfJoker, tblPrediction.GameID
    FROM (tblUser INNER JOIN (tblPool INNER JOIN tblUserPool ON tblPool.PoolID = tblUserPool.PoolID) ON tblUser.UserID = tblUserPool.UserID) INNER JOIN (tblResult INNER JOIN tblPrediction ON tblResult.GameID = tblPrediction.GameID) ON tblUser.UserID = tblPrediction.UserID
    GROUP BY tblPrediction.GameID, tblPrediction.Joker, tblResult.GroupName, tblPool.PoolID
    HAVING (((tblPrediction.Joker)=True) AND ((tblResult.GroupName)='A') AND ((tblPool.PoolID)=314));
    ORDER BY Count(*) DESC
```

Comment: Answer 1 nearly worked. When there are many counts with the same value, the query returns many rows in the output. But when i remove the order by count(*) desc, it only returns the first count, even if it is not the biggest count.

Comment: try `ORDER BY CountOfJoker DESC` (not sure if it works in MS Access)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to test it.
I don't really understand, why access returns multiple rows but can't you just process the first one only and ignore the others?
If not, I'm afraid I cannot help you.